# What is the effect of the Weave being broken in an area?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic

The Weave can be broken: maybe just by time or a legendary magical battle. What effect does the Weave being broken have on the world and creatures in the area where it is no longer intact?

Relevant snippets from "The Weave of Magic", 5e PHB:

> By any name, without the Weave, raw magic is locked away and inaccessible; the most powerful archmage can't light a candle with magic in an area where the Weave has been torn. ... And in places where the Weave is damaged or torn, magic works in unpredictable ways—or not at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Weave is an idea that D&D 5e has imported from the campaign setting *The Forgotten Realms*. As with most things the 5th edition of D&D imported from the campaign settings attached to previous editions though, it leaves much of the *facts* up to the DM — such as which planes even exist, and how the Weave works, beyond the details it gives.

## In D&D 5e

In D&D 5e, that quote of yours is the only information given on what happens where the Weave is broken. It provides the basic idea, and then leaves it up to the DM to build their own facts on top of it.

The idea with this approach is to allow the Truth to be different for different campaign settings. If a DM wants broken Weave to be a void of chaos, or instead to make it simply be a place of no magic, the DM can do that — the D&D 5e game has left DMs that flexibility by not deciding the facts for anyone.

However, D&D 5e has imported the concept of the Weave *and* the idea that the Weave can be damaged from a particular source: The Forgotten Realms, where these are well-documented. D&D 5e is unusual in that it is the first edition to make the idea of “the Weave” part of the core game. To learn more then (assuming a DM doesn't want to gleefully make up their own answers), we have to look backwards to where “the Weave” concept came from.

## In the Forgotten Realms

The Weave in the Realms is pretty much as described in D&D 5e. In addition though, it has been well-established what broken parts of the Weave do since the early 1990s (in 2nd edition AD&D): these areas are known as **[dead magic zones](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Dead-magic_zone)** and **[wild magic zones](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Wild_magic)**. Notice that D&D 5e hints at these origins: “magic works in unpredictable ways” is making a reference to wild magic zones, and “or not at all” is making a reference to dead magic zones.

### What does it look like? What does it do?

Both dead and wild magic zones *look* normal. They're not detectable except by trying to cast magic in them and then noticing that it doesn't work right.

In a wild magic zone (an area where the Weave has been damaged, but not destroyed), spells often or always don't work as intended, and are replaced by different spells and effects.

In a dead magic zone (an area where the Weave is completely broken), magic simply stops working and cannot be used.

Apart from these effects on magic though, there are no visible effects, and no adverse effects on creatures or objects in the zone. Creatures that rely on magic in some way (e.g. a beholder's ability to levitate) would obviously be negatively impacted by their magic abilities not working, but in the example of a bird, the bird would be completely unaffected.

Comment: Yes. this is pretty much exactly what i wanted. Tyvm

Comment: @Timi You're welcome! This is what I thought you were getting at — I just needed to figure out whether the additions to the question were guesses at what kind of thing the answer might be, or if they were more important parts of the question.